# Angular Material mat-menu-item to be the same size as the mat-menu button

Tags: css, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular-material2

I use mat-menu of Angular Material with different mat-menu-item and I would like the list of menu items to be the same size as the button.

That's what I have:

[image]

And what I wish:

[image]

I tried to change the size of the menu with the css, but it does not work properly.

CSS:

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {width: 100%;}
.mat-menu-panel {width: 100%;}
```

HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="btn-block btn-blue">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    <span fxFlex>OPTION</span>
  </div>
</button>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>unarchive</mat-icon>
    <span>First</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>file_copy</mat-icon>
    <span>Second</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

I did a [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-with-min-width-of-button) for my mat-menu.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT :** I changed my code because I'm using a responsive button with the bootstrap class "btn-block".

Comment: replace .mat-menu-panel {width: 100%;} with .mat-menu-panel {width: 100%; padding: 0 10px;}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution really not clean, but here it is: [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-with-min-width-of-button-2)

If someone would have a CSS solution, I'm interested.

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="btn-block btn-blue" id="button">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    <span fxFlex>OPTION</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck{
  ngDoCheck(){
    var widthButton=document.getElementById("button").offsetWidth;

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-menu-panel');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].style.width = widthButton+"px";
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {width: 100%!important;}
.mat-menu-panel {max-width: 100%!important; min-width: 64px!important;}
```

**DEMO:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `::ng-deep` to style `.mat-menu-panel`

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel {
  padding: 0 10px!important;
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-with-min-width-of-button-fxvmyz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: This won't work if you increase the width of the button. It also adds a padding to the left and right of the menu items thus breaking the material style of the menu.

Comment: In my project the button is responsive, the size is not fixed. 
I changed that in my StackBlitz

Comment: Ng deep is close to being deprecated. The equivalent to it is just adding the style in main styles.css file, without ng-deep of course.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody still needs this. Here is my [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppcjbo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

The idea is to read matMenuTriggerFor clientWidth, pass it to the menu itself as matMenuTriggerData, and bind it to the wrapper width

Comment: does that still work with angular 16...

Comment: yes, with slight changes. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4arlr?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Answer (score 1):

Since ::ng-deep is going to be deprecated,

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

another trick is to create margin around text span (mx-4 is bootstrap class for margin left and right

```
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>file_copy</mat-icon>
    <span class="mx-4">Second</span>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use menuOpened event for matMenuTriggerFor and add width runtime

**HTML**:

```
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="btn-block btn-blue"  (menuOpened)="onMenuOpened()" id="button">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    <span fxFlex>OPTION</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

**TS**:

```
onMenuOpened() {
    const btn = document.getElementById('revisitSection');
    if (btn) {
      const elems = document.getElementsByClassName('button') as any;
      // for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      //   elems[i].style.width = `${btn.offsetWidth}px`;
      // }
      for (const item of elems) {
        item.style.width = `${btn.offsetWidth}px`;
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't recommend to use ngDoCheck. it has more performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

For those searching this in the future your can set this in your

```
.mat-menu-panel {
  min-width: fit-content !important;
  padding: 0px 0px !important;
}

.cdk-overlay-pane {
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

To make the mat-menu dynamic then you can apply with and styling in the component css of ts file through [ngClass]="getClassWithWidthandHieght()".Through css set the class of the in side div to the class like this  the apply the styling set you styles.

```
.example-panel{
```

min-width: 500px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide your CSS class in `class` wth `mat-menu`, like below:

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="custom-wrapper-for-menu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>unarchive</mat-icon>
    <span>First</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>file_copy</mat-icon>
    <span>Second</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```